# Connectedness of covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose we have a covering map $f:E \to B$, where $B$ is a connected and path-connected space and $E$ is a p-sheeted cover of $B$.
Are the following statements equivalent?

1. $E$ is a non-trivial covering, i.e. $E$ is not a disjoint union of $p$ copies of $B$.
2. $E$ is connected.
3. $E$ is path connected.
4. There exists a loop in $B$ whose preimage is an interval in $E$.

I think the equivlance between 1 and 4 is easy to see since a trivial covering will have the property that the preimage of any loop is a disjoint union of $p$ loops. But I don't really understand the relation between 1 and 2 or 1 and 3. Definitely when $E$ is trivial, it is neither path-connected nor connected, but what about the other way around?

Or, is there any way to see if the covering space is connected/path-connected by looking at the covering map?

Any comment/help is appreciated.

Comment: No, they're not equivalent. First of all you need $p > 1$ or else $f = \text{id}_B$ shows that 1 is not equivalent to the others. But $E$ could be a disjoint union of nontrivial covers which shows that 1 is not equivalent to 2 or 3. I think 2 and 3 should be equivalent and 1 and 4 should be equivalent.

Comment: Where does this come from? Is $B$ connected and *locally* path-connected ?

Answer (score 2):

1 and not 2/3: a union of two non-trivial coverings.

2/3 and not 1: $f = \text{id}_B$.

2 and not 3: take the famous counterexample, make it path-connected:
[image]

and cover it spirally, as in the universal cover for $S^1$. Or do the same with the so-called extended long line, which is imo more fun. (Obviously, you can make p finite by modifying this way other $S^1$ coverings.)